# Good accuracy on training images but bad accuracy on test

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I followed the tutorial of Adrian Rosebrock ( multi-label classification [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/)) to classify the hand digit sign, I've trained a model using VGGnet model and Keras library, the plot showed after training indicate that the model should work fine.

The model gives good predictions only on training image, but when I test an image from the web, it gives me false prediction,

- Good prediction on the training image:

[image]

- False prediction on the testing image ( from the web )

[image]

[image]

- Source Code:

```py
EPOCHS = 30
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 16
IMAGE_DIMS = (130, 130, 3)

# grab the image paths and randomly shuffle them
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)

data = []
labels = []

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)


    l = label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2].split("_")
    labels.append(l)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
print("[INFO] data matrix: {} images ({:.2f}MB)".format(
    len(imagePaths), data.nbytes / (1024 * 1000.0)))


print("[INFO] class labels:")
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels)

for (i, label) in enumerate(mlb.classes_):
    print("{}. {}".format(i + 1, label))


(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
    labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=False, fill_mode="nearest")


print("[INFO] compiling model...")
model = SmallerVGGNet.build(
    width=IMAGE_DIMS[1], height=IMAGE_DIMS[0],
    depth=IMAGE_DIMS[2], classes=len(mlb.classes_),
    finalAct="sigmoid")

opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)

# compile the model using binary cross-entropy rather than
# categorical cross-entropy -- this may seem counterintuitive for
# multi-label classification, but keep in mind that the goal here
# is to treat each output label as an independent Bernoulli
# distribution
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the network
print("[INFO] training network...")
H = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

What are the reasons that make a model gives false predictions on test images?

Comment: How many images you used in training and validation? Why are you using `binary_crossentropy"? Do you have more than two classes right? I think you should use `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` as mentioned in this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification). Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed the tutorial of Adrian Rosebrock ( mentioned in the post ), and  I didn't want to change anything in metrics used like loss function and optimizer algorithm. I have six classes ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),  for the images I set, 20% for validation and 80% for training

Comment: This indicates that your model does not 'generalize' well. The information you have provided is not enough to determine what is the problem with your problem. It could be overtraining, or incorrectly tuned hyperparameters. One thing that I noticed is that the training image is not similar to the test one. If the model is trained on all images like the training image posted by you, then I am sure it would have a hard time with other ones. Kindly provide link to the dataset....

Comment: What do you mean by that I doesn't provide enough information to determine the correct problem? I have posted the code and images that describe the problem that I have. Please if you need anything else, feel free to indicate it in comments, for the dataset, you can find it by following this link https://github.com/ardamavi/Sign-Language-Digits-Dataset/tree/master/Dataset/0

Comment: Can you try to do image augmentation like horizontal flip for the training data and check the accuracy.